# egg_info failed with error code 1 for pip install in python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, pip

I've recently done a clean install of Python 3.6 on my Windows 10 laptop. 
I wish to install BeautifullSoup. When i try to use

```
python -m pip install BeautifulSoup
```

it returns the following:

```
C:\Users\mjpvanzuijlen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36>python -m pip install BeautifulSoup
Collecting BeautifulSoup
  Using cached BeautifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\MJPVAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-kopzhsyx\BeautifulSoup\setup.py", line 22
        print "Unit tests have failed!"
                                      ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\MJPVAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-kopzhsyx\BeautifulSoup\
```

I found others with similair problems with egg_info, but the solutions did not work for me. I have tried to upgrade pip, i downloaded setuptools32.3.2.1, i've upgraded setupttools but all to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to install the wrong package.

Try running: `python -m pip install BeautifulSoup4`

instead of: `python -m pip install BeautifulSoup`